# string to integer conversion c++

Tags: c++, string

This is the code to convert 12 hr time format to 24 hour format.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdio>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string s;
    cin >> s;

    int n = s.length();
    int hh, mm, ss;
    hh = (s[0] - '0') * 10 + (s[1] - '0');
    mm = (s[3] - '0') * 10 + (s[4] - '0');
    ss = (s[6] - '0') * 10 + (s[7] - '0');

    if (hh < 12 && s[8] == 'P') hh += 12;
    if (hh == 12 && s[8] == 'A') hh = 0;

    printf("%02d:%02d:%02d\n", hh, mm, ss);

    return 0;
}
```

I seem to understand the underlying logic of the code but unsure about string to integer conversion in the following lines of code:

```
hh = (s[0] - '0') * 10 + (s[1] - '0');
mm = (s[3] - '0') * 10 + (s[4] - '0');
ss = (s[6] - '0') * 10 + (s[7] - '0');
```

Answer (score 1):

`'0'` - is char

`'0' + x` where x integer from 0 to 9

`'0' + x` - frequently used conversion integer from 0 to 9 to char from '0' to '9'

so

`(s[6] - '0') * 10 + (s[7] - '0')`

is conversion two char string like '00' or '59' or some like this to integer 0 or 59 for that cases

Comment: The characters is organized  in order '0', '1', '2' etc... especialy for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> hh = (s[0] - '0') * 10 + (s[1] - '0');
> ```

`s[0]` returns a `char`, and `'0'` is a `char` as well.

So you are subtracting one `char` from another `char`. Same for `s[1] - '0'`, of course.

**A `char` is really just a number**, much like an `int`, just that you often use the type to represent a character, for example a letter or, in this case, a digit.

For example, the character `'A'` is very likely represented by the number 65 on your computer and with your C++ compiler.

---

I say *"likely"* because unlike what other answers are telling you, **C++ does not guarantee ASCII**. You may get away with it on almost any computer you will ever encounter, but portable code must not assume ASCII.

---

Just like `'A'` or any other letter, the digit `'0'` is also some integer number behind the scenes. Same for all the other digits. What makes your code work is the fact that while C++ does not guarantee ASCII, it *does* guarantee that the **integer representations for the digits `'0'` to `'9'` are consecutive**. So, for example, you *can* actually count on the integer representation of `'2'` to be the one for `'0'` plus two.

This of course also matches the way in which ASCII represents the digits, using numbers from 48 to 57.

---

The rest is simple math. Let's say the string starts with "12", so `s[0]` is `'1'` and `s[0]` is `'2'`. It is thus guaranteed that `s[0] - '0'` is 1 and `s[1] - '0'` is 2.

`'0'` could be 42, `'1'` 43 and `'2'` 44. Or `'0'` could be 48, `'1'` 49 and `'2'` 50. It doesn't matter; the calculation will always work due to the aforementioned guarantee.

1 * 10 = 10. 10 + 2 = 12.

Here we go: `hh` is 12.

---

Of course, the code will produce chaotic results if you pass it some input string which does not correspond exactly to the expected format. And in a real program, you would use a dedicated library or the standard-library components from `<chrono>` to achieve your goals.

Answer (score -1):

Every `char` data type is stored in memory by it's ascii code, which is a number. This means that you can also do arithmetic operations with them.

Opening up any [ascii table](http://www.asciitable.com/index/asciifull.gif) you will see the numeric value for each character. And you can notice that characters from '0'-'9' have an ascii code from 48-57.

So when you subtract two char values like: `'9' - '0'` will end up doing this operation: 57-48, which is obviously 9 (the int 9, not the char '9').

Comment: ASCII is not guaranteed by C++.

Comment: I see, but is it guaranteed that the digits are in a continuous order? So you can do `'0' + 6 == '6'` no matter what the integer representation is?

Comment: Yes, both the C and C++ standards require that the values that represent the characters `'0'..'9'` are contiguous and increasing. So `'9'-'0'` is required to be 9, etc.

Answer (score -1):

This code doesn't convert string to integer it converts characters to integers using their ASCII codes. see here http://ascii.cl/. 
What this code

```
hh = (s[0] - '0') * 10 + (s[1] - '0');
mm = (s[3] - '0') * 10 + (s[4] - '0');
ss = (s[6] - '0') * 10 + (s[7] - '0');
```

really does is  that it converts the characters in the time format to integers by subtracting the ASCII 0 from the characters in the string.

Comment: ASCII is not guaranteed by C++.

Comment: Um, yes, it's converting a string to an integer value. Every conversion function will work character by character; that doesn't mean it's not working on a string. And, no, this conversion does not depend on the text being represented in ASCII.